# How to remove all x-dependent term in a maxima expression?

Tags: maxima

I have an expression that consists of functions of x and y, something like
ay+yf(x)+g(x)+bh(x)+k(y).
Is there a convenient method that removes all x-dependent terms and leaves ay+k(y)?
f,g,h,k are symbolic and not known functions.

As far as I know, dependence in maxima [defined with depends()] is only recognized in diff. I tried diff and then integrate/antidiff, but antidiff/integrate does not recognize y and b as constant, and gives an expression with integrals.

Comment: `sublist(args(ee), lambda([e], freeof(x, e)))` returns a list of terms free of `x`, where `ee` is the original expression you showed. Then you can say `apply("+", foo)` where `foo` is that list.